# Xcode Issue: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib

Tags: swift, cocoa, xcode8

I've finished working on a **Cocoa** (not iOS) application with Swift 3.  I've tested it on a desktop computer.  It works fine.  I've tested it on another desktop computer.  It works fine.  I have even managed to send it over to **iTunes Connect**.  But I have not submitted it because the same application fails to run on a MacBook Pro (2013).  Anyway, I've tested it on a MacBook Pro with a retina display.  That's when the entire problem started happening.  Actually, this desktop application ran on the same MacBook Pro a few days ago.  I think it was not sandboxed yet.  Now, every time I send a binary copy that runs on different iMac models to MacBook Pro through AirDrop and try to run the application, I get an error that says `EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)`.  So I've deleted some files inside `Developer` /`Xcode` / `DerviedData.`  Now, I cannot even debug the application.  When I debug it, it hangs up with a fatal error message, which I have never seen before.

[image]

Now, if I double-click on an application that Xcode has generated, I get a crash report that says **Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib**.  I thought that I might have deleted some system files by accident.  But if I debug existing macOS and iOS apps, I have no problem running them.  Fortunately, the entire problem occurs on this particular Xcode project.

One topic that I've found here suggest that we set the **Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries** option to **Yes**.  I've done that with no vail.  I have also read a suggestion that says something about setting the `When using this certification` option on a developer certificate to `Use System Defaults`, which doesn't help.  Another suggestion that I've tried is clearning cache (Command + Shift + Option + K).

If you have any suggestions, please let me know.  Thanks.

**More information**

I have also seen a bizarre alert message repeatedly on MacBook Pro that says **"%@" cannot be found**.  This error message poped up when I double-clicked on the application icon.  It may refer to

```
String(format: NSLocalizedString("whatever", comment: ""), variable name)
```

Answer (score 7):

I have solved the problem! I had the same problem with you. But from the answer in https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/4nac9s/using_swift_frameworks_with_command_line/, I have known that the key is the rpath.

So I try to add this path to the project in the following two settings:

```
${DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/usr/lib/swift/macosx/
```

1. Runpath Search Paths
2. Library Search Paths

I don't know why need to add both the two settings, but it works!

Comment: These two paths are both the same

Comment: I only needed to add to **Runpath Search Paths** in macOS 10.12. Also if you're targeting other SDKs, you'll need to use `/iphonesimulator/`, `/iphoneos/`, etc. If you target multiple platforms, you can add all of them.

Comment: But now your application will only work on machines that have Xcode installed in the same path as you, I should think.