# Where are the "Search Paths" options in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, rpath

I reference [Xcode Issue: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721938/xcode-issue-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftappkit-dylib) to fix my problem. However I do not know where "Runpath Search Paths" and "Library Search Paths" are. I am using Xcode 10.1 (which is not relevant).

For reference, this is the error I am getting.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwizzleSrc.framework/Versions/A/SwizzleSrc
  Referenced from: /Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swizzler-cocjohzjocaharaexffmnddnjecc/Build/Products/Debug/swizzler
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking how to reconfigure your project so you can do a new build? Or do you want to change the paths in a binary you've already got?

Comment: I have an embedded framework I made that is in the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Xcode,

1. Select Project
2. Select Target
3. Select Build Setting
4. Type 'Search Path' in Search Box
   (or both 'Library Search Paths' and 'Runpath Search Paths')

Comment: Nothing there: tried "Search Path", +s, "Runpath"+ and "Library"+

Comment: Found it, now getting:
```log
2019-01-27 21:02:46.522519-0500 Terminal[31401:2319367] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
2019-01-27 21:02:46.523590-0500 Terminal[31401:2319367] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
```

Comment: That seems to be different issue with this question, creating new topic is better I think. Rather related with the page you've linked in question, maybe?